# How to make a span to overlap text inside td?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/9nvGM/

When the user hovers mouse on `long text` span, the span is expanded and the size of the `td` changes. I want to prevent this change. I'd like `td` to have the same size no matter how long the inner span is. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although you can make the width of the td bigger this gives only limited options as far as the length of the label goes, another safer solution is to position the span absolutely relative to the existing span, as can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/9nvGM/6/

HTML:

```
<span class="label"><span class="long label">long long long text</span>long text</span>
```

CSS:

```
.label{
    position:relative;
}
.long{
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    display:none;
}
```

JS:

```
handlerIn = function(e) {
  span.find(".long").show(); 
}
handlerOut = function(e) {
  span.find(".long").hide();   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

set the td to have position relative and the span to be positioned absolutley and then set the position of the span and perhaps the width. The span needs to be displayed as block too. This should cause the span to stay where it is and it will overlap anything in its way. The span should behave a bit like a tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

basically idea is to fix the width either of the td or the span

```
span
{
    width:50px;
    overflow-x:scroll; /* or hidden */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this css rule

```
td {
    max-width: 87px;
}
```

Try it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/markus85/9nvGM/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use min-width and max-width for your td then you have what you want

CSS

```
.tds{
max-width: 60px;min-width: 60px;
}
```

[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9nvGM/16/)

Answer (score 0):

there is nowrap style in .lable class.
just remove it by set white-space to normal .

```
.label{
    width:55px;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    white-space: normal !important;
}
```

like this :
http://jsfiddle.net/9nvGM/17/